# c# check if datagridview column contains value & linq First() vs FirstOrDefault()

Tags: c#, linq, datagridview

I need to check if first column in `DataGridView` contains value 10

I used this

```
int index = -1;  
index = (dgv.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()  
        .Where(r => r.Cells[0].Value.Equals(10))  
        .Select(r => r.Index)).First();
```

but sometimes produce error: Sequence contains no elements

Someone on this forum sugested to use `FirstOrDefault()` no `First()`

Thats work BUT if first column in first row contains value 10 
or there are no rows where first column contains value 10, variable index have value 0

My solution was:

```
try {
 index = (dgv.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow> ()
  .Where(r => r.Cells[0].Value.Equals(10))
  .Select(r => r.Index)).First();
} catch {
 index = -1
}
```

Best regards,

Comment: Do you mean to say, if first column in first row contains value 10 then assign its index to `index` variable otherwise assign 0 to it. Kindly elaborate your question with some test data and expected output

Answer (score 5):

> I need to check if first column in DataGridView contains value 10

Right tool(method) for the  job would be `.Any`, which returns `true` if any item from the collection satisfies given condition, or false if not or collection is empty.

```
if (dgv.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().Any(r => r.Cells[0].Value.Equals(10)))
{
    // exists
}  
else
{
    // not exist
}
```

In case you really need an index value, use `.DefaultIfEmpty` method to return default value for the case when collection is empty or required value not found.

```
var index = dgv.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()  
    .Where(r => r.Cells[0].Value.Equals(10))
    .Select(r => r.Index)
    .DefaultIfEmpty(-1)
    .First();
```

With `.DefaultIfEmpty` you can "tell" readers of your code your actual intention without extra conditions or null propagators.
And because you provide default value in case empty collection returned, you can safely use `.First()` method because at least one item will be always returned.

For finding all occurrences of given value, don't use `First` or `FirstOrDefault`.

Answer (score 0):

[As MSDN says about First()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.first?view=netframework-4.8):

> Returns the first element of a sequence.
>   **The First(IEnumerable) method throws an exception if
>   source contains no elements.** To instead return a default value when
>   the source sequence is empty, use the FirstOrDefault method.

[In addition what MSDN says about FirstOrDefault():](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.firstordefault?view=netframework-4.8)

> Returns the first element of a sequence, **or a default value if no
>   element is found**.

Try to use `FirstOrDefault()`:

```
int index = -1;  
index = (dgv.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()  
    .Where(r => r.Cells[0].Value.Equals(10))  
    .Select(r => r.Index)).FirstOrDefault();
```

UPDATE:

From ["Fixing LINQ Error: Sequence contains no elements"](https://blogs.msmvps.com/kevinmcneish/2009/12/17/fixing-linq-error-sequence-contains-no-elements/):

> When you get the LINQ error "Sequence contains no elements", this is
>   usually because you are using the First() or Single() command rather
>   than FirstOrDefault() and SingleOrDefault().

You can reproduce your error:

```
int[] numbers = { };

int first = numbers.First(number => number > 800); // OUTPUT: Sequence contains 
                                                   // no matching element
```

Comment: I did not understand what OP is saying *Thats work BUT if first column in first row contains value 10 or there are no rows where first column contains value 10, variable index have value 0*. How you interpreted this sentence to answer a question. May be I am missing something It would be great if your answer explains OPs problem with solution

Comment: Your update does not clarifying issue which OP is facing

Comment: @PrasadTelkikar I've added an example to my answer, maybe it will clarify

Comment: @PrasadTelkikar I think Fabio has made the best answer:)

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is :

```
int index; 
var row = dgv.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().FirstOrDefault(r => r.Cells[0].Value == 10);
if (row != null)
    index = row.Index;
else
    index = -1; // or whatever you want
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your problem correctly then you are trying to assign first index values which satisfy condition, if there is no record then assign `-1` to index.

To solve this issue, you can use [null coalescing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator) operator with [`FirstOrDefault()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.firstordefault?view=netframework-4.8), like

```
int index = dgv.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
                .FirstOrDefault(r => r.Cells[0].Value.Equals(10))?.Index 
                 ?? -1;
```